# Concatenate multiple instances of complex data structure in python

Tags: python, database, pandas

To give some background: often in experimental science we have a set of probes at different locations that record some variables (temperature and velocity here) in time. These probes may be interrupted at certain times and so what we are left with are chunks of restart data that just continue where the previous data set ended. I have created an example data set to show this, and now the only thing is to find an elegant way of concatenating the "chunks" of data collected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dimS = 1  # dimension of a scalar variable
dimV = 3  # dimension of a vector variable
Np = 3    # number of measurement locations 
Nt = 10   # time samples 


def create_single_probe(Nt):
    """
    Create fictitious data for a probe
    """
    probe = {}
    probe["temp"] = np.random.rand(dimS*Nt).reshape(dimS,Nt)
    probe["velo"] = np.random.rand(dimV*Nt).reshape(dimV,Nt)
    probe["loc"] = np.random.rand(3)
    return probe



def create_multiple_probes(Np,Nt):
    """
    Gather mutliple probes into dict
    """
    probes = []

    for i in range(Np):
        probes.append(create_single_probe(Nt))

    data = {}
    data["time"] = range(Nt)
    data["probes"] = probes

    return data


# Create data that we want to concatenate 
restarts = [create_multiple_probes(Np,Nt) for i in range(3)]


# Now we want to concatenate the entries of restarts 

def concat_complex_dict(restarts):

   # Solution here...    

   return concat_data
```

in this example the location of the probe for each restart location will change with the new restart data, but this is not the case in reality.

After concatenation I expect the following:

`concat_data["time"]` to be a list or array of length 30

`concat_data["probes"]` to be a list of length 3 (since there are three probe locations) where each entry is a dictionary such that the `i`th entry we have

`concat_data["probes"][i]["temp"]` is an array length 30 and
`concat_data["probes"][i]["velo"]` is an array length 3x30

I can make a very laborious solution whereby I go through all the elements of my dictionary that I want concatenate with a bunch of lists but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way maybe using pandas...

I hope it makes sense what I want to do and any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: pandas is for flat data, with rows and columns. If you find a way to express your data in flat format, then joining them with pandas will be straightforward. However, what you're presenting looks more like a key-value database to me.

Comment: Yes I think you are right about this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I followed the explanation correctly and made the correct assumptions (veloctiy is in X,Y,Z format), here is my suggestion for a more readable format. If I'm close I can change it to be more reliable, if I'm off I will remove.

```
dimS = 1  # dimension of a scalar variable
dimV = 3  # dimension of a vector variable
Np = 3    # number of measurement locations
Nt = 10   # time samples

def create_single_probe(Nt):
    """
    Create fictitious data for a probe
    """
    probe = {}
    probe["temp"] = np.random.rand(dimS*Nt).reshape(dimS,Nt)
    probe["velo"] = np.random.rand(dimV*Nt).reshape(dimV,Nt)

    '''Create dataframe'''
    mat = np.concatenate([probe['temp'].reshape(Nt,dimS),probe['velo'].reshape(Nt,dimV)],axis=1)
    frame = pd.DataFrame(mat,columns=['temp','VelocityX','VelocityY','VelocityZ'])
    probe["loc"] = np.random.rand(3)

    '''Add location of probe as comma separated string'''
    frame['loc'] = ",".join(map(str,probe['loc']))
    return frame



def create_multiple_probes(Np,Nt):
    """
    Gather mutliple probes into dict
    """
    probes = []

    for i in range(Np):
        df = create_single_probe(Nt)
        '''Set time as a row value for each probe'''
        df['time'] = range(Nt)
        probes.append(df)

    '''Concat into one dataframe'''
    data = pd.concat(probes)

    return data

print create_multiple_probes(Np,Nt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think this is getting there, however it would be nice to have a solution that doesn't need to copy the probe locations for each time as the probe location is fixed, thus allowing saving of data. Otherwise it looks good!

Comment: No problem, if you want to eliminate the location column you could do a multiIndex, by adding `data.set_index(['loc','time'],inplace=True)` before return of the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which should work. However it is tremendously ugly, and difficult to follow...

```
def concat_complex_dict(lst):

    cdata = {}

    # Concatenate the time data 
    first = True
    for x in lst:
        time = x["time"]
    if first:
        ctime = time
        first = False
    else:
        ctime = np.concatenate((ctime,time))

    cdata["time"] = ctime


    cdata["probes"] = []


    # Concatenate the probe data 

    nLoc = len(lst[0]["probes"])
    for i in range(nLoc):
    dic = lst[0]["probes"][i]
    cprobe = {}
    for key, _ in dic.iteritems():
        first = True
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if first:
            cprobe[key] = np.atleast_2d(lst[j]["probes"][i][key])
            first = False
            else:
            if key == "loc":
            break # dont concatenate the location as it doesnt change
            cprobe[key] = np.concatenate((cprobe[key],lst[j]["probes"][i][key]),axis=1)

        cdata["probes"].append(cprobe)

    return cdata
```